# Starting a application with graphical interface on boot

Tags: bash, unix, centos

I have a small question that I havn't found any answers to.

I run a virtual machine on my CentOS server, and I have made a simple script to start the virtual machine. I would like to run the script on boot so that the virtual machine starts up on boot also. So I successfully registered the script with following

```
chkconfig --add myscript
```

and enabled it with following

```
chkconfig --level 2345 myscript on
```

at last I checked it so its registered and enabled correctly with

```
$ chkconfig --list | grep myscript
```

So long, so fine, but when I restart my machine to test it, well nothing happens.
So now I wonder why isn't my script running? I had some thaughts that it cold be because of some missing arguments, myscript requires an argument "start" to run properly, so I think that could be the cause why it's not running, in that case where should I add the argument?

Note also, my script is ok, or at least I can run it manually.

UPDATE

The script is run during boot and is working as it should. Tha application I try to start with a script, my virtal machine, has a graphical interface and it seems like it's that causing the trouble. Does anyone have any experience in starting a graphical application with script on boot, on unix based OS's ofcourse? Or if there are any other clever ways of achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: put `echo $(/bin/date +%Y%m%d:%H%M%S) :starting myScript >> /tmp/myScriptStarter.log` to confirm it is actually running? If windows was involved anywhere, `dos2unix myScript`. Confirm permissions are ok `/bin/ls -l myScript`, if not `chmod 755 myScript`. Good luck.

Comment: okey @shellter I echoed to file now and indeed the script does run but  my virtual machine is not starting, however the script maybe is running to early, because I don't want to run my virtual machine headless, so I think it's something with that

Comment: also agree with @socalcheeshead. Do you understand about, AND have implmented correctly your  /etc/init.d and /etc/rc.?/ scripts and symlinks? Good luck.

Comment: What virtual machine provider are you using? I believe both VirtualBox and Libvirt allow you to specify whether you want a specific vm to start up at boot.

Comment: Is it so @JasonZhu? I use VirtualBox, do you know how to enable this or know any article about this?

Comment: @shellter, From what I can understand the `rc.local` is run at last during boot and it's there I have created the symlink to my script, because I want to run it so late as possible. This is how I understand it. Once more, the script runs fine when running it manually, also I get a log entry in my logfile indicating it runs during startup. But I believe this is something to do with that's an graphical application I want to start.

Comment: arg.. graphical application. Is it an X-windows app? If so you need a Xserver running someplace, often the same machine as your app. I have only ancient and minor experience with anything graphical, so I wish you luck resolving your problem. Best to update your main question with your most up-to-date description of the problem.

Comment: @RobertNyholm I was under the wrong impression that boot on start is natively supported by Virtualbox. However [Vboxtool](http://vboxtool.sourceforge.net/) seems promising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the proper symlinks get created in /etc/rc.?/ and your startup script in /etc/init.d/ should contain start and stop methods.

Comment: yes my script contains start and stop methods and I have added symlinks in the rc files but it refuses to start

Comment: no I don't see any errors at all, it seems to be working fine. Read my comments above.

Comment: That was going to be my next question, whether it's a graphical interface that you're trying to launch and if so i'm not entirely sure what the behavior is/should be.